# Nativescript using repeater multiple key value

Tags: javascript, android, ios, repeater, nativescript

I am trying to use repeater to display json data. But the result is not like what I want. What I want is the the Item is displayed after the Value. not Value displayed all after that Item displayed all.

here is the page.bindingContext :

```
page.bindingContext = {
"myItems": [
    {
        "value": "100",
        "item": "Car"
    },
    {
        "value": "200",
        "item": "Motor"
    },
    {
        "value": "300",
        "item": "Boat"
    }
]
};
```

and here is the xml template :

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout cssClass="bodyPilihProduk">

  <Repeater items="{{ myItems }}" style="font-size:12;">
     <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{value}}" margin="10" />
     </Repeater.itemTemplate>
  </Repeater>

  <Repeater items="{{ myItems }}" style="font-size:20;">
     <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{ item }}" margin="10" />
     </Repeater.itemTemplate>
  </Repeater>

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the result is : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about use Repeater once, and print two items?

Edited: added orientation="horizontal"

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout cssClass="bodyPilihProduk">

  <Repeater items="{{ myItems }}" >
     <Repeater.itemTemplate orientation="horizontal">
        <Label text="{{ item }}" margin="10" style="font-size:20;"/>
        <Label text="{{value}}" margin="10" style="font-size:12;"/>
     </Repeater.itemTemplate>
  </Repeater>

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now you can display both items and values.

iOS

[image]

Android
[image]

Comment: the result is only show the {{value}} items. the {{item}} not showing.

Comment: strange. still only show the {{value}} items in android emulator.

Comment: I am try using ListView, and it works

`            <ListView items="{{ myItems }}" >
                <ListView.itemTemplate>
                        <StackLayout verticalAlignment="center">
                            <Label text="{{ item }}" textWrap="true"  style="font-size:30;margin-bottom:20;"/>
                            <Label text="{{ value }}" textWrap="true"  style="font-size:30;margin-bottom:20;"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>`

Comment: @Dilar Glad to hear that. And, up to my knowledge, this code should be works.

Comment: You can also try placing the labels in a StackLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use one (1) repeater and print both labels in it. As you have two items, you need to wrap them in some kind of [layout](http://docs.nativescript.org/layouts.html). To just print them after each other, a StackLayout with `orientation="horizontal"` will suffice.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Repeater items="{{ myItems }}">
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label text="{{ item }}" />
                <Label text="{{ value }}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
</ScrollView>
```

Any [layout](http://docs.nativescript.org/layouts.html) would work, here's an example using the GridLayout which will give you a more of a table look with two columns, items in the first column and values in the second.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Repeater items="{{ myItems }}">
        <Repeater.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout columns="4*, 1*">
                <Label col="0" text="{{ item }}" />
                <Label col="1" text="{{ value }}" />
            </GridLayout>
        </Repeater.itemTemplate>
    </Repeater>
</ScrollView>
```